# Jquery Datepicker remove days of previous or next month from the current month

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I'd like to remove days of previous or next month from current viewing month to let you understand exactly what I mean I'll attache the screen shot where I highlighted exactly what I need to remove

[image]

I've tried this code

```
$('.ui-state-disabled').html('').closest('td').removeClass('highlight-date');
$(document).on('click', '.ui-datepicker-next', function(event) {
    $('.ui-state-disabled').html('').closest('td').removeClass('highlight-date');
});
$(document).on('click', '.ui-datepicker-prev', function(event) {
    $('.ui-state-disabled').html('').closest('td').removeClass('highlight-date');
}); //removes all days of previos month from the current month
```

it removes the days however when I click on a day it reapears

this code

```
$('.ui-state-disabled').html('').closest('td').removeClass('highlight-date');
```

does not work in the datepicker settings like onSelect or beforeShowDay:

what is the solution, I really need to remove the days

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are off by default.
You add these properties to your datepicker to show them:

```
showOtherMonths: true,
selectOtherMonths: true
```

https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#other-months